# Play count / Last played statistics intermittently don't update in iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod

I have an iPod classic (160GB) which I sync with iTunes 10.6.0.40 using automatic syncing.

Generally, when I plug the iPod into my PC via USB, all of the **Play count** and **Last played** statistics update properly.

Yesterday I listened to 5 albums on my iPod, in the following order:

1. The Pogues - If I should fall from grace with God
2. Apples in Stereo - Fun trick noisemaker
3. Joni Mitchell - Court and spark
4. Led Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin III
5. Underworld - Dubnobasswithmyheadman

However, when I plugged the iPod into my PC, iTunes only showed that I had played the last 2 albums (Led Zeppelin, Underworld) and it was as if the other albums hadn't played (their **Last played** dates were back in 2010).

Any idea what may be causing this?

Why doesn't iTunes respect my diverse taste in music?

**Edit:** I have since upgraded to iTunes 10.6.1.7 and I am still seeing this issue, so I am now offering a bounty to anyone who can help me solve this.

Comment: Does the "Recently Played" list update in your iPod?

Comment: @Andrew - it's updated on the iPod after I play the albums, but once I hook the iPod up to iTunes, it's like I never played certain albums (i.e. they don't appear in the Recently Played list on either the iPod or iTunes, and the Play Count/Last Played stats don't show the albums as having played recently).

Comment: Try this: In the left-hand pane, right-click the name of the playlist, choose Edit Smart Playlist, and make sure that "Live Updating" is checked.

Comment: @Andrew - thanks.  It is already checked.  I don't think this is an issue with the "Recently played" playlist (or any playlist for that matter).  As I said, the iPod/iTunes forgets that I ever played it (i.e. the Last Played date may be some date in 2010 despite the fact that I played it yesterday).  And yes, the date/time on both my iPod and iTunes is accurate.

Comment: Does the play count update correctly when you play the same albums locally (i.e. in iTunes)?

Comment: @kopischke - Yes, they do.

Comment: It looks like it's a [common problem](https://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:discussions.apple.com+itunes+ipod+sync+%22last+played%22+problem+automatically+sync&oq=site:discussions.apple.com+itunes+ipod+sync+%22last+played%22+problem+automatically+syn&fp=8c877c7548188a3b) - [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3923784?start=0&tstart=0)'s another person with a 160GB iPod Classic who believes their problems are due to the introduction of Match - could this be the cause of your issue? Also [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16663785#16663785) for iPhone